# Initializing an object in a method and creating a copy of it in another method

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize a string array with 3 empty strings in a `static void` method. Then I make a copy of that `string array` in another `static String[]` method.

I have tried several ways to do this, but what is the best way to do this?

```
public static void createEmptyStrings() {
      String[] str = new String[]{"", "", ""};
}

public static String[] copyStrings() {
// return an empty string
}
```

Comment: Show your attempts along with the problems you encountered.

Comment: Why make a copy of an array filled with empty strings? Simply create a new one: `new String[]{"","",""}`. The empty string instance will get reused.

Comment: The logic being that I would put the method into a loop and initialize the strings everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public static String[] getStrings(){
    String[] strings = {"", "", ""};
    return strings
}

public static String[] copyStrings(String[] stringArray){
    return stringArray.clone();
}

// Sample Usage
String[] originalStrings = getStrings();
String[] copiedStrings = copyStrings(originalStrings);
```

The `.clone()` method is very helpful in java to create a copy of an object and not just reference it as many people accidentally do.

If you want the array to have 3 slots that are empty instead of being filled with "" than change line two to:

```
public String[] strings = new String[3];
```

Comment: but i would need the first part of the initialization to be in a static void method, since I would need to call it multiple times